# django-form show form data after saving it

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to show same data to user as posted by him using form after saving it in database.
I am not getting the logic for it.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def CreateDeal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DealForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
            data = form.data
            return render(request, '/path_to/deal_detail.html',data=data)
```

Is it ok ?
Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: How about using `form.cleaned_data` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, a redirect of the "detail" page will resubmit the form. This is generally not desired behaviour.

A better way would be to create a detail view for you saved object (if you haven't already) and redirect the user to the detail view of that particular object:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def CreateDeal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DealForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('deal-detail-view', args=(obj.id,)))
            # or return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url()) 
            # if `get_absolute_url` is defined
```